# Freezes after hitting F11

Tags: fedora, freeze

I'm using Fedora (Workstation) 27.

Everything is good and fine, except for one thing:
When I press F11 to go into full-screen mode in Chromium or in Visual Studio Code, my computer freezes. It freezes. **Freezes heavily**. REISUB can't help. Can't open a TTY terminal. Can't kill X11 interface. It freezes so heavily that any input doesn't matter.

I checked and I'm sure that F11 is the shortcut key to go into fullscreen mode in Chromium, and that there's no match of the F11 key shortcut in Settings.

Also, I have to mention that upon hitting the F11 key, the CPU fan goes crazy.

How am I supposed to deal with such a problem?

Comment: could you hit `F11` at a specific timestamp reboot and extract log at the timestamp in files like: `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog` ?
That would be an excellente start.

Comment: Fedora 27 has neither. It uses only `journalctl` by default.

Comment: Then provide `journalctl` output. Anyway, there' s no way people will help with that much few informations

Comment: Reminds me a little of a weird minecraft bug I have where if I minimize the game it does exactly this... What graphics chipset and driver are you using, out of curiosity? And have you tried a) disabling acceleration in these apps and b) running them in a different window manager/with a different compositor/without a compositor?

Comment: I checked `journalctl` and only found a bunch of `key repeat discarded wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough`. Looking on this.